Yahoo Fantasy API no longer seems to work anymore? Consistently getting token_rejected when it worked a few days ago
For the past few weeks I've been using the Yahoo Fantasy API successfully to work on a side project of mine. However this weekend I started getting a "token_rejected" error no matter if I have a valid token or not. The code I have WAS working, but when I went to test/develop this weekend, it just stopped working and started getting these errors.
What is bizarre is that I can indeed use the Yahoo Login API (SSO/OAuth2.0 flow) to successfully retrieve a user_token and refresh_token, but I can't use it on any of the https://fantasysports.yahooapis.com -- I am however, able to use the access token to send requests to the https://api.login.yahoo.com/openid/v1/userinfo endpoint.
The "app" that I create in the Yahoo Developer page has all the access/permissions I need, but it just doesn't work anymore. I am certain something has changed in the API side on Yahoo... does anyone know what's going on? If not could someone who uses the Yahoo API see if it works for them? I am going crazy and I'm really bummed that all my progress on my side project has come to a halt :(
Here is some code in Node (v20) for the two API requests I send, one works the other doesn't. Replace access_token with your access_token.
// valid user_token
const USER_TOKEN = "REPLACE_ME"
let authHead = "Bearer " + USER_TOKEN;

// this API request works with the bearer auth token
fetch('https://api.login.yahoo.com/openid/v1/userinfo', {
    method: "GET",
    hostname: "api.login.yahoo.com",
    headers: {
        "Authorization": authHead
    }
}).then(res => res.text()).then(res => console.log('user info ',res)).catch((e) => console.log(e))

// this one does not
fetch('https://fantasysports.yahooapis.com/fantasy/v2/users;use_login=1/games;game_keys=nfl/teams?format=json', {
    method: "GET",
    hostname: "fantasysports.yahooapis.com",
    headers: {
        "Authorization": authHead
    }
}).then(res => res.text()).then(res => console.log('fantasy api result ',res)).catch((e) => console.log(e))

Result:
fantasy api result  {"error":{"lang":"en-US","description":"Please provide valid credentials. OAuth oauth_problem=\"token_rejected\", realm=\"yahooapis.com\""}}
user info  {"sub":"my_id","email":"my_email","email_verified":true}

I did find this https://github.com/whatadewitt/yahoo-fantasy-sports-api/issues/118 issue that two other people are running into it but I really just don't know... I e-mailed Yahoo as a last resort too.
My question here: is anyone running into this same problem, does anyone know if anything changed? Or am I at the mercey of Yahoo here? Seriously? No wonder people webscrape lol
